# Loop through the array (key by key) | the keep checking each key by adding it to the path

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop

I just have an idea, but not sure if this is even possible (I really hope that someone can help me with this).

As example if we have array - `arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]`

I would like to create a loop of checking JSON path by using the above array, something like this:

```
def jsonLoop(loadedJson):

    arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

    for i in range(len(arr)):

        if jsonPathChecker(loadedJson,i,arr) is not False:
            return jsonPathChecker(loadedJson,i,arr)


def jsonPathChecker(loadedJson,i,arr):

    if i == 0:
        jv = loadedJson[arr[0]]
    elif i == 1:
        jv = loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]]
    elif i == 2:
        jv = loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]
    elif i == 3:
        jv = loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]]
    elif i == 4:
        jv = loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]][arr[4]]
    elif i == 5:
        jv = loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]][arr[4]][arr[5]]

    if isinstance(jv, list):
        return jv # or return I so I will know where the array starts
    else:
        False
```

BUT I would like to have the ability to go infinitely with `i` and instead of creating a long list of if statements

Comment: Is there a reason you're checking for `if isinstance(jv, list):`? A json path can end withf list, numbers, strings, dictionaries, etc.  Isn't it sufficient that the path exists and you're given the terminating value?

Comment: @DarrylG I was checking for an array for that can start looping to dir deeper + it is another question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def jsonPathChecker(loadedJson,i,arr):
    jv = loadedJson[arr[0]]
    for ix in range(1,i):
        jv = jv[arr[ix]]
    if isinstance(jv, list):
        return jv # or return I so I will know where the array starts
    else:
        False
```

Comment: I'm sorry, please correct me if I'm wrong, but your solution will not add a key to the loadedJson, but instead will check only the first/second key and that it ...

Comment: Note that `jv = jv[arr[ix]]`. This means that after each iteration, you will be one level deeper in the structure.

Comment: Thank you I did not know that you can do this way, (I'm about this line `jv = jv[arr[ix]]` )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to reduce the `if` judgment.
How about this:

```
def jsonPathChecker(loadedJson,i,arr):
    
    jv_dict = {0: loadedJson[arr[0]], 
               1: loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]],
               2: loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]],
               3: loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]],
               4: loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]][arr[4]], 
               5: loadedJson[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]][arr[3]][arr[4]][arr[5]]}
    
    jv = jv_dict[i]
    if isinstance(jv, list):
        return jv
    else:
        False
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking to covert jv_dict into some kind of looping mechanism, so that if we will have a path with `arr[100]` I do not need to add tons of code....

Comment: @MR Sample  ok, maybe `Hugo Guillen` answers is right.